# Creating SessionScoped Bean again for particular request

Tags: jsf-2

How to create sessionscoped bean again for any particular request.
e.g. I have page1.xhtml represented by Job Bean (session scoped) and page2.xhtml by Process bean (Session Scoped), after processing the request from Processing bean, rendering again page1.xhtml, but the datatable mapped with the Job bean in page1.xhtml not reflects the changes i made in Processing bean.

How can i make those changes visible i made from other page.

Comment: Why is the bean session scoped if you apparently need it to be view scoped?

Comment: Hi BalusC, bean is session scoped because there are some values need to keep in session only.

Comment: Just split those values into a separate bean so that you have a session scoped bean for session scoped data and a view scoped bean for view scoped data. It isn't making any sense to choose the wrong scope for the data it holds and manually fiddle around with destroying the wrongly scoped instance. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/